# check an item collection value mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to know what can I do to check an intem of a collection in mongodb.
the function that I describe below insert users in the db and I would check before the insert if the username exists.

```
exports.adduser = function(db) {
return function(req, res) {


    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
    var userCod = req.body.usercod;


    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.insert({
        'username' : userName,
        'email' : userEmail,
        'cod' : userCod

    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {

            res.send('There was a problem adding the information to the database.');
        }
        else {
            res.location('userlist');
            res.redirect('userlist');
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var collection = db.get('usercollection');
collection.count({username:username}, function(err, count){
  if(err){
    return callback(err);
  }
  if(count > 0){
    return callback('User already exists!');
  }

  //do your insert operation 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know diddly squat about node.js, but lookups in MongoDB are on the Collection object as find() and findOne().  Assuming your username is enough to make a record unique, the "check if exists" would look like

```
if ( collection.findOne( { "username" : userName } ) != null ) {
    println("username " + userName + " exists!" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious approach would be to add a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on `username`, which will ensure you can't insert duplicates.

The error handling logic will be similar to what you've sketched out in the question description. If a `username` already existed, there would be an exception when trying to insert and the `err` string would be something like "E11000 duplicate key error... " (including the offending duplicate key).